# Detect bet regex

Tags: c#

When I receive a number I want to check it against all the potential bet combinations, e.g.

```
L( 24, 25, 26, 27)
```

Would return true if I was searching for the number 24 but not 2, hope I'm clear, sorry for no code I'm a newbie.

Comment: What is `L( 24, 25, 26, 27)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool ChechResult(int value)
{
    String input = @"L( 24, 25, 26, 27)";
    String pattern = @"\d+";
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    {
        if(value == int.Parse(match.Value))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(subject, " " + 24 + "(?:,|\\))");
```